# How to rename the attachment when using mailx?

Tags: linux, email, date, unix, mailx

How to rename the file that is being attached in the email when using mailx?
Further, wondering to see if it is possible to add date to the attachment.

For example:
cat /home/msgsubject.txt| mailx -r someone1@somewhere1.com -s "Email" -a /home/auto.log someone2@somewhere2.com

So here I want see the attachment auto.log to be attached as auto_02272015.log

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
cp /home/auto.log /home/auto_02272015.log

cat /home/msgsubject.txt| mailx -r someone1@somewhere1.com -s "Email" -a /home/auto_02272015.log someone2@somewhere2.com
```